# Jenkins can't find C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\apktool\framework\1.apk

Tags: android, jenkins

When I use Jenkins to execute awindows batch command when building the project, it throws out an error :

[image: Error log]

Jenkins can't find the dictionary C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\apktool\framework. How can I fix that?

Comment: The exception is :
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command:

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I see that you've added a comment with extra information about the exception. That's good, but it would be better if you edited your question to include the extra information; that way, the reader has everything in one place so they can understand your problem more easily.